# Why Select statement returns only 1 column?

Tags: python, sqlite

I try to print the 3 columns:

1. Artists.artist
2. Songs.Song
3. Songs.views

This is my code:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('utube.db')

conn.row_factory = lambda cursor, row: row[0]

c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("""Select Artists.artist, Songs.Song ,Songs.views FROM Songs 
          INNER JOIN Artists
          ON Artists.Artist_Id = Songs.Artist_Id
          """)

allsong = c.fetchall()

a = allsong        
print(a)
         
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

But the output returns only `Artists.artist`.

```
['Blackpink', 'Blackpink', 'Lady gaga', 'Lady gaga', 'Lady gaga', 'The Beatles', 'The Beatles', 'Metallica', 'Frank Sinatra', 'Frank Ocean']
```

How to fix that to make it returns something like

```
[['Blackpink',?,?],['Blackpink',?,?],['Lady Gaga' ,?,?]........]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this line will select only the first column of each row:

```
 conn.row_factory = lambda cursor, row: row[0]
```

Try taking that out and see if you get the whole row.